# get list of all loaded / created Symbols in swift

Tags: swift

How do I get list of all symbols / variables / functions in Swift.

Other languages have a function (example dir() in python) and (%who in ipython)

Comment: Are you looking to log all instance variable in the current program scope?  In the entire program?

Comment: yes; I am looking to log all instance variables